# ICP 3.1.0 Vagrant support

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

*I used * [1]: https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/blob/master/docs/deploy-vagrant.md
to install ICP 2.1.0.3 on my mac.

Does it support also ICP 3.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, I believe this tool cannot be used to install ICP 3.1.0 because the relevant `icp-inception` image has not been added to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/icp-inception/). When that image is available, the tool *might* work if you change the version parameter on line 22 in the [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private/blob/master/Vagrantfile).

Even with the correct image, there may be other configuration steps that need to be taken such as changing the `k8s_version` or the `memory` requirements, since these have changed in 3.1.0.

EDIT: The image is now available on Docker Hub, but I have not tested configuring the vagrantfile to install 3.1.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I used it successfully to install ICP 3.1 on my Linux PC. I just had to set

```
version = "3.1.0"
```

in the Vagrantfile.